# How would you describe the feeling of feeling like being treated unfairly?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, when two siblings of different ages are told to go to bed at the same so the older one feels "..." ?

Comment: This depends entirely on the individual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try **mistreated**.

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mistreat) carries the following definition:

> **mistreat**
>
> *verb [ T ] UK​ /ˌmɪsˈtriːt/ US​ /ˌmɪsˈtriːt/*
>
> **to treat a person or animal badly, cruelly, or unfairly**:
>
> *Both parents have denied charges of mistreating their children.*
>
> *I think people who mistreat their pets should be banned from keeping them.*​

Quite a broad spectrum of bad behaviour is encompassed in *mistreatment* but the rest of the sentence makes it clear that it is not actual abuse you have in mind, rather something much milder.

---

**Aggrieved** would also work.

[The same dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/aggrieved) defines *aggrieved* as follows:

> **aggrieved**
>
> *adjective uk ​ /əˈɡriːvd/ us ​ /əˈɡriːvd/* 
>   ​
>   **unhappy and angry because of unfair treatment**:
>
> *He felt aggrieved at not being chosen for the team.*
>
> *One aggrieved customer complained that he still hadn't received the book he had ordered several weeks ago.*

*Aggrieved*, a cognate of *grief* and *grievance*, puts useful emphasis on the perceived injustice of the situation, which suits your example sentence well. Compared to *mistreated*, with *aggrieved* the  feelings of the child about the unfairness of the whole thing rather than the unjust actions of the adult is the difference in sense.

[The Online Dictionary of Etymology](https://www.etymonline.com/word/aggrieved#etymonline_v_40882)'s entry throws up a few useful near synonyms too - and is interesting in itself:

> **aggrieved** *(adj.)*
>
> c. 1300, "**annoyed, incensed, resentful, angry**;"
>
> late 14c., "**oppressed in spirit**,"
>
> *past-participle adjective from* aggrieve (v.).
>
> The legal sense of "injured or wronged in one's rights" is from 1580s.

*Oppressed in spirit* strikes me as a peculiarly appropriate description of how the elder child might feel here!

---

**Indignant** is another option.

A definition follows, again from [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/indignant):

> **indignant**
>
> *adjective UK​ /ɪnˈdɪɡ.nənt/ US​ /ɪnˈdɪɡ.nənt/*
>
> **angry because of something that is wrong or not fair**:
>
> *She wrote an indignant letter to the paper complaining about the council's
>   action.*
>
> *He became very indignant when it was suggested he had made a mistake.*

With *indignant*, the sense is very much of righteous anger, bristling at the injustice of it all, although it should be noted *indignant* can definitely be used when the offence is a trivial one.

---

You could also say the elder child felt **hard done by**.

Clearly, this isn't a single word (and this is a *single word request*) but the phrase suits the context very well so it would be remiss of me not to at least mention it.

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/feel-hard-done-by?q=hard+done+by) defines it as follows:

> **feel hard done-by**
>
> *also* **feel hard done-to** *UK*
>
> **to feel that you have been treated unfairly**:
>
> *I'm feeling hard done-by because I've been taking care of the kids all week and Steve's been out every night.*

(I can't personally attest to the dictionary's UK alternative version, *feeling hard done-to*, as I don't think I've ever heard it, but I have no reason to doubt the source either.)

The sense of *feeling hard done by* is much like feeling *aggrieved* (upset rather than angry), although *hard done by* would not suit a formal register well.

---

Of these, I think *hard done by* and *indignant* are perhaps most appropriate to the situation described in the example sentence, although *aggrieved* or *mistreated* might better suit more formal contexts, or work better if a different nuance is required.

Comment: I’m not a big fan of the shotgun spray approach to answers on EL&U.  It prevents one from up-voting a good answer buried in with some not-so-good ones.  What should OP conclude when this answer is up-voted? That each option presented is equally viable and they can pick any of them with equal assurance?

Comment: @Jim It felt presumptuous to populate the question with lots of answers but what you say makes total sense. I'll edit now and bear that in mind in future.

Comment: @Jim ...or I will do so, if the question is re-opened. Nonetheless, point taken, and something I will definitely avoid doing.

Comment: I think "mistreated" and "hard done-by" are the closest to what I have in mind. But to be honest, I never heard "aggrieved" and "indignant" before.

Answer (score 3):

The word I'd use is **cheated**:

> If you feel cheated, you feel that you have been let down or treated unfairly.
>   <sub>[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/feel-cheated)</sub>

For example:

> Some people spend their whole lives resenting siblings or feeling cheated by siblings who were favored by the parents.
>   <sub>[When Someone's Adult Sibling Dies - LegacyConnect](http://connect.legacy.com/profiles/blogs/when-someones-adult-sibling-dies)</sub>